# PHP strtotime not working for date and day of week

Tags: php, date, strtotime

Here's an odd one... pretty sure this is a strtotime issue, but would love some assistance as to why this would be partially working...

CODE:

```
$dateReturnedFromMySQL = '2014-09-22 18:00:00'
$startDate = strtotime( $dateReturnedFromMySQL );
$startMonth = date( 'M', $startDate );
$startDate = date( 'd', $startDate );
$startDay = date( 'D', $startDate );
$startFullDate = date('M d, Y', $startDate );
```

The variables $startMonth, $startDate are outputted correctly. (Sep, 22 respectively)

The variable $startFullDate returns as Dec 31, 1969 (clearly a strtotime issue, but not sure why?)

The variable $startDay always returns as Wed (again, clearly a strtotime issue, but not sure why?)

Comment: You set the `$startDay` and `$startFullDate` to another `$startDate` on line `$startDate = date( 'd', $startDate );`? No?

Answer (score 5):

You are overwriting your original variable:

```
$startDate = date( 'd', $startDate );
^^^^^^^^^^ here
```

You should use a different name for that.